# How can I convert an integer to a character in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, integer, character, mips

I want to convert an integer value into a character, and then want to print that character as a 'character'.

```
# convert an word into bye and print it
.data
    integer: .word 1

.text
    la $a0, integer # load the address of 'integer' into $a0
    lw $t0, ($a0) # load the value stored in address
    addi $t0, $t0, 31 # convert digit to a character

    # print the character
    move $a0, $t0 # prepare the value for printing
    li $v0, 4 # syscall value for a character
    syscall

    # exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Output:

```
Assemble: assembling number_to_character.asm

Assemble: operation completed successfully.

Go: running number_to_character.asm

Error in number_to_character.asm line 13: Runtime exception at 0x00400018: 
address out of range 0x00000020

Go: execution terminated with errors.
```

The programs seems to be not working. Probably, because of the size difference between an integer (word) and a character (byte).

Comment: System call 4 prints strings. The system call for printing single characters is 11. Also, to convert to a character you should add 48, not 31. And the assembler understands `'0'` as 48, so you don't have remember ASCII codes.

Comment: @Michael, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOHXggt2EDk     this guy is using 4 and apparently it worked.

Comment: It would work if you wrote back the character to `integer` and then passed `integer`'s address to system call 4, simply because the three most significant bytes of the word are zero. That's not what you are doing, and using system call 11 would be the simpler solution for you.

Comment: @Michael, can you kindly elaborate your last comment? I haven't understood. Coz, that guy in the youtube is using a byte along with a syscall-4. What if I do an AND operation to remove unused byte

Comment: System call 4 expects `$a0` to contain the **address** of a zero-terminated string. That's not what you're giving it. I'm not sure why you insist on using system call 4 when you only want to print a single character, for which there is a dedicated system call (11).